# Debug query with offical mongodb golang package (command monitoring)

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to print mongodb query created with "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo" package. Is there any option to take a look at the query produced by this package or dump it in any way? I can go inside mongod instance and modify profiling level and see the queries from mongod, but it's not the right way.

Comment: This is called command monitoring, see e.g. https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-monitoring/#command-monitoring.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. Unfortunately go mongodb package has the worst documentation ever created :/

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to user D. SM I've got a code sample to achieve monitoring of all logs.

```
cmdMonitor := &event.CommandMonitor{
    Started: func(_ context.Context, evt *event.CommandStartedEvent) {
        log.Print(evt.Command)
    },
}
ctx := context.Background()
clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(connectionString).SetMonitor(cmdMonitor)
```

Comment: docs: https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#ClientOptions.SetMonitor