# How can I record and replay MongoDB requests?

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm writing integration tests for a Go program that queries a MongoDB cluster using [Mongo Go Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver).
I'd like to record those requests and later replay them in the tests.

Is there a library that I could use?
I'm currently familiar with 2 similar libraries, but those are used for different purposes:

- https://github.com/google/go-replayers
- https://github.com/cockroachdb/copyist

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: why don't you use setProfilingLevel? https://stackoverflow.com/q/15204341/9391162

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69902182/9492730. Mongo drivers allow subscription on events that happens in the driver.In particular `CommandSucceededEvent` event happens when the command successfully has been sent to the server

Comment: recent driver releases should allow logging, see here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/logging/

Comment: as for replaying, I'm not sure I understand your goal, but you can run any raw MQL query (for example recorded via events) via runCommand, see here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/run-command/.